# Openshift Python Execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I have a python application that needs to be run 24/7. I have employed openshift to do this. I have managed to get the files up on openshift. However if I want to execute this application, how do I go about doing this. This particular application has an executable python file that needs to be run to run the application.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense. What do you mean by 'managed to get the files up on openshift'. Are you using the Python S2I builder? If you have already deployed the application and OpenShift says it is running, then some process is already running. What Python web framework are you using? Do you have an ``app.py`` file or ``wsgi.py`` file? Is ``gunicorn`` listed in the ``requirements.txt`` file by chance already?

Comment: Are you on the starter or pro version of Openshift 3?  The starter version does support cron and has to hibernate at least 18 hours every 72 hrs.

Comment: I am using starter. The files are stored in a repository on github that is connected to openshift. That is what I meant by got the file up.

Comment: Sorry.  Autocorrect got me again.  Openshift 3 starter DOES NOT support cron jobs.

Comment: Here is my Openshift 3 python pyramid stater app.  It has the bare minimum configuration. http://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift_3_Pyramid_Starter?files=1.